# Как сделать глобальную функцию?

Tags: yii, yii2

Как сделать глобальную функцию? Это которая доступна из любого места всего веб-приложения.

Насколько я вижу, то есть два способа это сделать

**1.Сделать контролёр**

**2.Сделать виджет**

Но, возможно есть лучший способ. Какой?

Comment: Вам нужен класс со статической функцией.

Comment: @Onedev.Link а какой класс?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, _со статической функцией._

Comment: @Grundy а как к нему получить доступ?

Comment: `class Test{ 
 public static function helloWorld() { 
  echo 'hello, world'; 
 } 
}` вызов `Test::helloWorld();`         http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский этот файл php , который содержит этот класс, нужно же еще в пространство имен подключать?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов ну да...например делайте этот класс как отдельный компонент...распологаете его в `components`...называете его, например `Helper` или `Common` (а ля `class Common extends Component  {`), где будут собраны все вспомогательные функции .....эти все функции (точнее методы) можно (если нужно) делать статическими

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Я это делал, но что то не заработало, поэтому решил написать сюда. Сейчас буду тестировать где я ошибся. Спасибо.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский еще же можно reguire - как в node js

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов не знаю о чем вы...... а ошибиться вы могли.. если только например забыли указать этот самый компонент в конфиге.....или не используете неймспейс при использовании

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Да, в конфиге я не указал. Не очень бы хотелось конфиг трогать и расширять. Даже и не знаю теперь. Наверное все-таки reguire - include  , сделаю.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов конфиг на то и создан и поэтому так и называется. `КОНФИГУРАЦИЯ`.... в котором должны лежать все необходимые конфигурированные данные приложения он и должен по ходу работы расширяться... добавляться настройки маршуртизации, используемые компоненты, список ассетов, используемые логи, модули и прочее...там же не просто задаешь айдишник приложения и всё......в этом идея же ж

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Дело в том, что не рекомендуется его слишком сильно расширять, потому как могут возникнуть проблемы с производительностью  при загрузки  первой страницы.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Ну удачи вам в разработке тогда :-)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Ну, спасибо. Вам так же.